# Expectation of a random variable conditioned on two other random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $X = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ be a discrete random variable and $Y$ and $Z$ be continuous random variables distributed uniformly from over the ranges $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$, respectively (with $Y$ and $Z$ independent of each other). There are no restrictions on the values of $a,b,c$ or $d$. How would I work out $\mathbb{E}[X | Y, Z]$?

I guess we could start with,

$\mathbb{E}[X | Y, Z] = \mathbb{E}[X_1 | Y, Z] + \mathbb{E}[X_2 | Y, Z] + \mathbb{E}[X_3 | Y, Z]$,

but I am not sure how to deal with the conditional being on both Y and Z.

Edit: $X_1, X_2 = f(Y,Z)$ and $X_3 = g(Z)$

Comment: Nothing can be said about $E(X\mid Y,Z)$ because the problem is underspecified. Post-edit, it is still underspecified. You need to specify a dependence structure between $X$ and $(Y,Z)$

Comment: Please can you explain what extra information is needed rather than just stating it is underspecified? I have added some.

Comment: @AndrewZhang I have added what I think you mean by 'dependence structure'.

Comment: Then $E(X_j\mid Y,Z) = X_j$ for $j = 1,2,3$, by definition of conditional expectation